# How to program Objects in JS based on elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I am trying to build clean object oriented code in JavaScript which is closely connected to HTML elements.

The situation I try to solve is a page where there are multiple suggestions given.
Every suggestion has a few options, and every option has a button to active it.
A simplified snippet of the HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="row suggestion">
    <div class="span6">
        <ul>
            <li data-id="1">
                <span>Option 1</span>
                <span><a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">pick me</a></span>
            </li>
            <li data-id="2">
                <span>Option 2</span>
                <span><a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">pick me</a></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
       <button>Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know how to script this without the use of objects, but since i want to add more functionality to suggestions I want to take the clean OO approach.
I expect you known the benefits of OO and take my choice

What I tried thus far looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var suggestions = [];

    $('.row.suggestion').each(function(){
        suggestions.push(
            new Suggestion($(this))
        );
    });
});

function Suggestion($el){
    var options = new Array();

    $el.find('a').each(function(){
        options.push(new Button($(this)));
    })
}
Suggestion.prototype = {
    childChange : function(){
        // do some checks;
    }
}

function Button($el){
    this.$el = $el;
    this.id = $el.parents('li').data('id');
    $el.click(this.onclick);
}
Button.prototype = {
    checked : false,
    $el : null,
    id : 0,
    onclick : function(){
        // set this button active
        // notify my parent suggestion that i've changed
    }
}
```

It works as expected up to the onclick function.
When it is triggered the function is started but the scope changed.
I thought I would have access to the object but I'm limited to the scope of the jQuery instance of the clicked element.

I've had a few idea's but they all had their caveats:

- adding all the attributes and functions to the specific DOM elements, 
  but i couldn't figure how to do that OO
- using jquery.data() for adding the attributes to the element.
  but i couldn't figure how to add the function to the jquery instance.
- using another library like Prototype, YUI3 or a specific design pattern. So I started reading at:

  - http://prototypejs.org/learn/extensions.html
  - http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/ (the first half at least)
  - a few blog posts about YUI3

Till this moment I can't find a known solution to Object Oriented programming in JavaScript which is closely connected to the elements on a page. All OO JS examples I find don't have elements as their starting point. 
All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You do realise the way you've done `var options` in `Suggestion` basically hides it from everything, forever, once `Suggestion` has been constructed?

Comment: Say there are two _Object_ s, _A_ and _B_. _B_ is a property of _A_. Properties and methods of _B_ have no way of knowing that _A_ is a "parent" of _B_ unless _B_ has a property (which is set to _A_) you define as such. However, that would be a circular reference and can be bad.

Comment: You are correct, i would fix this later on. But I focused on finding a solution for the scope first.

Comment: Maybe im out of topic, but you should consider to use a framework, e.g AngularJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.proxy()` for that:

```
$el.click($.proxy(this.onclick, this));
```

Then `onclick` will be called in the context of your `Button` object.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would go for a more maintainable OO pattern.

Then, to relate to elements, you simply have to make them an instance property.

```
var myApp = {};
myApp.dom = {};
myApp.dom.Suggestion = function(options) {
   this.container = document.createElement("option");
   this.options = [];
   for (var i = 0, len = options.length; i < len; i++) {
       this.options[i] = document.createElement("option");
       this.options[i].setAttribute("value", options[i]);
       this.options[i].addEventListener("change", this.change.bind(this), false);
       this.container.appendChild(this.options[i]);
   };
};
// now you already have two properties, the suggestion container and the options.
myApp.dom.Suggestion.prototype.change = function(event) {
    var currentOption = event.target;
};
myApp.dom.Suggestion.prototype.decorateElement = function(parent) {
   try {
      parent.appendChild(this.container);
   } catch (DOMException) {
      console.log("Specify a parent element");
   };
};
// now you have instance references to all your properties.
```

All you really need are abstractions on top of elements. A `Suggestion` would have a `select` as a container, if you make an `Option` class, it would have an `option` as a container, etc. Then add all the functions you need. The important part is to call the events in the right scope, and that can be done via `Function.prototype.bind`.

If you like this approach, then have a look at the Google Closure Library, everything is built in this style. Admittedly, it is a massive library with a lot of tools and using the library without the tools is not really efficient.

If you just want to get things done fast, use jQuery and  `proxy`.

```
this.container.change($.proxy(this.change, this));
```

And replace the native JS methods with jQuery methods to ensure cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Having `this.change.bind(this)` inside the loop will create lots of identical functions so eat up memory and cycles, you can move it above the loop and just pass a reference.

Comment: [`The bind() function creates a new function (a bound function) with the same function body as the function it is being called on`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). You can think of it a bit like a generator returning `function (new_this) {bind_me.call(new_this);}`, with parameters, etc.

Comment: yes, what I'm trying to say is that it doesn't simply return a reference, it returns a new function every time it is called, and this new function is necessary so that the JavaScript engine can store the `this`. Inside the bound function will be a reference to the original function (`arguments.callee`). You can quickly test if it is just a reference via [`===`](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6) (which says `false`).